# C++11 : error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, syntax-error, std

I am trying to do the following operation:

```
source = new int[10];
dest =  new int[10];
std::copy( std::begin(source), std::end(source), std::begin(dest));
```

However, the compiler reports the following error.

```
copy.cpp:5434:14: error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’
copy.cpp:5434:44: error: ‘end’ is not a member of ‘std’
copy.cpp:5434:72: error: ‘begin’ is not a member of ‘std’
```

I have included the required `<iterator>` header in the code. Can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Template functions std::begin() and std::end() are not implemented for pointers (pointers do not contain information about the number of elements they refer to) Instead them you should write

```
std::copy( source, source + 10, dest);
```

As for the error you should check whether you included header

```
#include <iterator>
```

Also maybe your compiler does not support the C++ 2011 Standard.

Comment: If you would define source and dest as int source[10], dest[10]; then indeed you could use these functions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to include `<iterator>`in C++11 enabled compiler. You should know `begin/end` are not useful for pointers, they're useful for arrays:

```
int source[10];
int dest[10];

std::copy(std::begin(source), std::end(source), std::begin(dest));
```

Comment: +1 But if he has access to C++11 features he should be using `std::array`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Agree, but sometimes a simple `[]` is not a bad choice for simple projects/codes.

Answer (score -1):

also have this problem when using g++ compiler this code in linux.

Using g++ compiler that contain C++ featuer should add C++11 flag

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```